# Android 2.3.3, create a line in a view

Tags: java, android, line, android-sdk-2.3

Trying to create a black line in my view to separate text blocks but its not showing up.
The text shows up as it should but i don't see the line.

EDIT:
Have tested to add both dynamically as suggested and also to modify my code but still no line? Am i missing something?

Also this is inside a Fragment, class extends Fragment {}

Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/travelContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Java code:

```
    public class Travel extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.travel_fragment, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.travelContainer);

        TextView text = new TextView(getActivity()); 
        int padding = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,4, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
        text.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
        text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        text.setText("TITLE");
        text.setId(123456789);
        layout.addView(text); 

        /* 
    View v = new View(getActivity());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewLp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);
    viewLp.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);
    v.setLayoutParams(viewLp);
    v.setBackgroundColor(0x000);
            */

    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.line, (ViewGroup)getActivity().getCurrentFocus(), false);
    layout.addView(v);


        text = new TextView(getActivity()); 
        padding = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,4, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
        text.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);       
        text.setText("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.");
        layout.addView(text); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to create the View programatically?

An easy approach is creating a View with following attributes

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000" />
```

If you create a new XML file called line.xml you can use a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to get the view dynamically:

```
View line = MyActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.line, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus(), false);
```

This version will result in a much cleaner code as the system does all the work for you.

Comment: Need to do it programatically since i am adding an unknown amount of views. The items are coming from the database.

Comment: You can still inflate that XML view programatically and use it dynamically. The code will be much cleaner. See in the edit for details.

Comment: Tried it but it still doesn't print a line for some reason.

Comment: Did you add the View to your LinearLayout? Works perfectly fine here.

Comment: Any difference if its a fragment? That code is inside the onViewCreated(View, Bundle) {} method of my fragment.

Comment: I found the problem. Changed the code and now its working.  
View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.line, (ViewGroup)layout, false);

Comment: Ah nice - so the current ViewGroup was a problem - didn't test it in a fragment. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

In your Layout params, you must set the height to 1, and the width to fill parent. You are only setting 1 of the height/width parameters aswell. Try the following

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewLp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);
viewLp.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);
```

Also, you are using LayoutParams for a RelativeLayout yet you are using a LinearLayout. LinearLayouts dont support the following:

```
viewLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 123456789);
viewLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Use LinearLayout.LayoutParams. LinearLayout will stack the Views, either horizontally or vertically, in the order they are added.

Comment: Tried it but no difference. It still doesn't print a line ?

Comment: what is your background color?

Comment: White, changed the line to purple to make it stand out.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar I think and an easy way is to overwrite the class of the component especially the onDraw() method you want to have the line separator.

I think your goal is too add a black line at the end of each textview, so you could do the following :

1) Create a png black line

2) declare a class extending TextView and overwrinting the onDraw method and doing the following ==>

```
private Bitmap line;
```

then in constructor :

```
    line = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.line_thin);
    line = Bitmap.createBitmap(line, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), 1);
```

then on the onDraw() method :

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(line, 0, this.getHeight(), null);
```

3) and finally you just don't forget to change the type of your component with the class your created in your XML.

I don't know if this solution fit to you but I think it's an okay one, then the line is dynamically created everytime you create this Textview.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Problem is that it's not always a textview. I also add images on the fly. Perhaps then create a class that inherits from TextView but only prints the line and nothing else. But how big line must it be then? 200px? 1000px?

Comment: I edited my code : when I create the bitmap it's now set to have your component width. To answer the question, it's just go for a loooong line, it will fit anyway. And about your on the fly add, you can just extend a/many component and overwrite the onDraw() method. You can basically add a line at the end of everykind of component you want.